# PHP MySQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection, code-injection

I have a PHP script with this code:

```
$sid = $_COOKIE['sid'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `sid` = '$sid' AND `use` <> 1");
```

In a MySQL table with name `users`, I have the following columns: `id`, `name`, `md5password`.

How can I do:

```
 UPDATE `users` SET `md5password` ='newpassword'`
```

with a potential SQL injection in PHP? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Quentin I don't think so. The OP seems to want to perform the injection.

Comment: @Andrew We need much more information as to what you are trying to do. I hope you know that we won't help you hack a site, right?

Comment: `'; UPDATE users SET md5password ='newpassword'; SELECT * FROM order WHERE sid = '1` .. theoretically

Comment: @JonathonHenderson won't work, see answer.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I put "theoretically". It's an example of how I would potentially attempt to perform an injection as the OP asked, even though the security restrictions on `mysql_query()` would stop it happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The reason is `mysql_query()` does not support multiple queries and so even with this SQL Injection vulnerability, you can't execute an `UPDATE` query.

The best you can do with this SQLi is to extract or read data from the database, you can't update or delete it.

Comment: Can I see the example of extract or reading?

Comment: Also, a deliberately malformed query can be entered in order to try to get an error message revealing the table structure.

Comment: I know structure of all tables and have source codes, and i need to get or change md5password column from `users` table via using vulnerability in PHP-code.

Comment: You can also read and write files.